# Same route nested in multiple resources ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an ember.js app which has a model called "Programme".

A user can drill down to a programme by going:
`Genre > Subgenre > Programme` or `Folder > List > Programme`

Here's my router:

```
this.resource('mylists', { path: '/' }, function() {
  this.resource('folder', { path: '/folder/:folder_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('list', { path: '/list/:list_id' }, function() {
      this.resource('programme', { path: '/programme/:programme_id' });
    });
  });
});

this.resource('catalogue', function() {
  this.resource('genre', { path: '/genre/:genre_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('subgenre', { path: '/subgenre/:subgenre_id' }, function() {
      this.resource('programme', { path: '/programme/:programme_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

The UI needs to be deeply nested (the genre view renders in the outlet of the catalogue template, the subgenre in the outlet of the genre template... and so forth).

The problem I have is as both generated routes are called `ProgrammeRoute` when I `linkTo` the programme route inside the list template, it actually goes to the programme route nested in the subgenre route.

What should I be doing here?

To work around it I've named one route `ListProgrammeRoute` and `SubgenreProgrammeRoute` but that leads to some duplication.

Comment: For now you need to name the two resources differently. You can share code between them with a mixin or base class to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [link-to helper with multiple models](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_supplying-multiple-models)?

```
{{link-to 'mylists.folder.list.programme' aFolder aList aProgramme}}
```